# How to add items from a List< > to another List< > using the same model

Tags: android, list, arraylist

I have 2 lists, I need to pass items from one list to another using the same
model, In this case, we call it Replies.

There is a uid on each reply, if the uid I provide equals to the uid of the reply, it should take that item and copy it to the `currentReply` list

```
List<Replies> allReplies;  //All replies are here
List<Replies> currentReply; //Replies that meet criteria should be added here

String prov_uid = 123456;
Replies replies = getValue(Replies.class);

if (allReplies.equals(prov_uid))
{
    currentReply.add()
}
```

Comment: Loop over `allReplies` and add to `currentReply` if condition is satisfied?

Comment: post Replies shema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work

```
for (Replies item : allReplies){
    if (<your condition>){
        currentReply.add(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: how to set this properly onBindviewHolder ,  it gives back visual glitches

Comment: I have tried i
                String m = mReplies.get(getAdapterPosition()).getComment_uid();
 but it throws me this error:
 java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=10; index=-1
        at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:439)
        at apps.stylizedAdapters.CommentsAdapter$ViewHolder.<init>(CommentsAdapter.java:539)